# Error: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Me sale el error:

> No module named 'mysql'.

No sé por qué, por favor ayuda

```
import mysql.connector

dbConnect = {
    'host':'localhost',
    'user':'root',
    'password':'w*#tzMpaC!t^R',
    'database':'hatting696',
 }

conex = mysql.connector.connect(**dbConnect)

cursor = conex.cursor()

sql = "select * from users"

cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()

print(results)

for data in results:
    print(data)
```

Comment: Pues no tienes el módulo mysql en python para importar .connector.

Comment: guía de instalación¿?

Answer (score 1):

Hola debes poner ésto en la terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install mysql-connector
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Instala el conector de Mysql abriendo una consola o terminal utilizando [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

verifica si se instaló con:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jul 15 2019, 16:40:56)
[GCC 4.5.2 20080704 (Debian 9.3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Si no te salta algún error después de `import mysql.connector` el módulo se instaló correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

escribe en la linea de comandos donde esta Python:

**python
-m pip install mysql-connector**

Luego verifica con:

**Python

> > import msql.connector**
> > si no da ningun error es porque se instalo succesfully.